# Write to Excel File with Pandas Module

Tags: python, excel, pandas

How could I write  a list of items `[1,2,3,4,5]` to an excel file in a specific tab starting at a specific row and column location using the `Pandas` module? Does it involve the `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel` function, and do I need to convert my `list` into a `dataframe` before writing it to the excel file?

Would I make the list into a series first, and then convert the series into a dataframe, and then write the dataframe to the excel file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will need to use 'to_excel'. The one line code below creates a list, converts it to a series, then converts it to a dataframe and creates and excel file

```
pd.Series([ i for i in range(10)]).to_frame().to_excel('test.xlsx')
```